# Is it possible to somehow open a bank account in Vietnam with a tourist visa of six months?

Tags: proof-provenance-of-funds, vietnam, visa-bans

I know that for opening a bank account in Vietnam a tourist visa of one year is required.

I consider staying in Vietnam six months or one year. Paying the one year visa fee is a bit "heavy" for me considering all other expenses so it is likely I will arrive to Vietnam with a visa of 6 months only (I also want to try living there to decide if I move to a third country for a while instead).

I am not Thai but I reside in Thailand and have a bank account in Thailand and might be able to bring a plausible *bank statement* from my bank in Thailand (say, ~75,000 Baht) to the Bang in Vietnam.

Is it possible to somehow open a bank account in Vietnam with a tourist visa of six months?

Is there any possible, legal, exception for the "1 month" condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need a 1 year VISA to open a bank account in Vietnam, so depending on country it means you need a 1 year business visa since many countries, including mine (Sweden), cannot have 1 year tourist visas but only 3 month multiple entry tourist visas.

Note however that there are talks that will change this year (2020) but so far those are the rules.

I am currently opening a company in Ho Chi Minh so I am going through these procedures myself at this very moment.